# specifc users attributes from different domains with a single powershell script

Tags: powershell, active-directory

In my environment we need to get specific users information from different child domains. With the help of powershell script I am getting result from one domain at a time. Is there any way to get multiple domain result with single script?

Please note that input files are different for different domains.

Comment: Off-topic, I want to suggest a StackOverflow maxim: "*Any question containing the word 'specific' is guaranteed to be too vague to answer*".

Answer (score 0):

As long as you're running in a user context that has the appropriate access to all child domains, or you can cache suitable credentials for every single child domain, yes, of course you can get "multiple domain result" with a single script.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have proper credentials, have you tried creating a loop containing all domains in the forest:

```
    foreach ($mydomains in (Get-ADForest).domains){...}
```